# Nodejs Azure Storage Copy Blob to New Blob

Tags: node.js, azure-storage

I have found good method of copy blob directly inside azure, `startCopyBlob` work pretty well. Is there any method similar to this one which copy container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The best way to do this is to list the blobs in the container and copy each one of them.

Comment: and if i don't have a list of those blobs?

Comment: i found listBlobsSegmented, i guess that is the answer, testing at the moment.

Comment: well i accept your answer, but this must be fixed by azure :)

Comment: Rather than listBlobsSegmented I'd advise using the regular listBlobs API. listBlobs has automatic continuation following whereas segmented makes you do that yourself.